# Prove existence of vector perpendicular to $n-1$ linearly independent vectors **without Gram-Schmidt**

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $\mathbf{u}_{1}$, $\mathbf{u}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{u}_{n-1}$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

With Gram-Schmidt, I can find pairwise perpendicular vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n-1}$ that span $\mathbf{u}_{1}$, $\mathbf{u}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{u}_{n-1}$. Take any vector $\mathbf{w}$ that is not a linear combination of $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n-1}$.
Then $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{w}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{v}_{i}}\mathbf{w}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n-1}$ and hence also to $\mathbf{u}_{1}$, $\mathbf{u}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{u}_{n-1}$.

**Without Gram-Schmidt**, how might I prove the existence of a vector $\mathbf x$ that is perpendicular to $\mathbf{u}_{1}$, $\mathbf{u}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{u}_{n-1}$?

---

Context: High school

Ideally (not sure if this is possible): Prove using only rules of arithmetic with real numbers and vectors (e.g. $(1,2)+(3,4)=(4,6)$, $3(1,2)=(3,6)$, $-(1,2)=(-1,-2)$, $(1,2)\cdot(3,4)=11$, $\mathbf u \perp \mathbf v \iff \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v = 0$) and **without** introducing such additional concepts as span, basis, dimension, vector space, matrix, row reduction, inverse of matrix, etc.

Comment: The condition of being perpendicular to $u_1, \dots u_{n-1}$ is a system of $n-1$ linear equations in $n$ variables, and it has at least one solution (zero), so it has at least a $1$-dimensional space of solutions by e.g. rank-nullity. I don't see how you expect to get away with using either a result at least this strong, in some form (e.g. row reduction). You already need something like this to prove the existence of $w$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Great thanks good to know that this is probably not possible. But I'll wait and see if anyone might have an answer for me.

Comment: You can generalize the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$: write down a formal determinant where the first row is $\mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_n$ and the rest of the rows are the coordinates of the $n-1$ vectors.